# Syntax help - HTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an `<a> </a>` inside of my datatable where I already had o use the ""´s right after return, but how do I pass my sub into my alert call?

```
function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    var sub = full[7].substring(0,21)+"...";
                   return "<a class='astyle'  onclick='new function() { alert('"+sub+"') }'>"+sub+"</a>";

                                }
```

My example is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `'` here:

```
onclick='new function() { alert(\'"+sub+"\') }'>
```

Full Code

```
function (data, type, full, meta) {
  var sub = full[7].substring(0, 21) + "...";
  return "<a class='astyle' onclick='new function() { alert(\'"+sub+"\') }'>"+sub+"</a>";
}
```

Best way to handle these would be split all the variables and get it done. Don't have one single variable with all the confusing quotes and codes.

Comment: Yeah I tried this variant too and I copied your code too but weird enough it still doesnt work, second `'` in alert doesnt get highlighted at all even in my PHP Storm

Comment: @ChrisFodor Don't just go with your editor boss. Editor is not a PHP interpreter and will not be powerful enough to suggest the runtime issues. It **won't** get syntax highlighted. But if you don't do this, it will throw an error in the front end. If you say, this doesn't work - for the editor highlight, please don't! It never works.

Comment: I understand that, but the alert doesnt show up either way. Edit: I got it to work like this:   `return "<a class='astyle' onclick='new function() { alert(\""+sub+"\") }'>"+sub+"</a>";`

Comment: @ChrisFodor Super... Thanks for letting me know... `:D` Have a nice day.